# What is the swift way of creating an Array of numbers of a certain pattern?

Tags: swift

The pattern of numbers I'm looking to create follows the pattern:

`[100, 200, 400, 800, 1600, 3200, 6400]`

I know I can accomplish this with a for loop but coming from languages like `Python` I wonder if there is a `Swift` way to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`sequence(first:next:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2015879-sequence) function. It creates an infinite sequence. You can then use `prefix` to get a finite number of elements.

```
sequence(first: 100) { $0 * 2 }.prefix(7)
```

If you then convert that to an array, you can print it out in a human readable format:

```
// [100, 200, 400, 800, 1600, 3200, 6400]
print(Array(sequence(first: 100) { $0 * 2 }.prefix(7)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use a `ClosedRange` as an array and `map` it. Technically still a for loop but in one line.

`(0...6).map{pow(2,$0) * 100}`

Comment: That would result in a decimal array. Not sure if thats what OP is expecting.